# Using AJAX to call a PHP function without data or form IN Laravel 7

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Hello friendly programmers!

I'm in kind of a situation right here. I'm working with Laravel 7 and my view has 2 buttons. 'start' and 'stop'
On click 'start' I want to create a row in my MySQL table which has the user_id of the user who is currently logged in and the timestamp at which the user pressed 'start'.
You probably already know what comes next: On click 'stop' I want to create a row with the user_id and the timestamp at which the user pressed 'stop'

I got only one route for the corresponding PHP function:
`Route::post('/home', 'HomeController@findAction')->name('home.find');`

That function looks like this:

```
    public function findAction(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->has('start-btn'))
        {
            return $this->dispatch(new \App\Jobs\WorkStart($request));
        }
        else if ($request->has('stop-btn'))
        {
            return $this->dispatch(new \App\Jobs\WorkStop($request));
        }
        else if ($request->has('pause-btn'))
        {
            return $this->dispatch(new \App\Jobs\WorkPause($request));
        }

        return 'no action found';
    }
```

The idea is that depending on which button is clicked a certain job would execute. The jobs are working quite good. I tried the same thing using a form which resulted in creating the rows I wanted. The downside is that everytime I clicked a button the whole site went white and I had to click back to go on. (I guess because of the nature of PHP post?)

The Jobs look like this:

```
class WorkStart implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        try
        {
            $id = DB::table('times')->insertGetId(
                ['user_id' => 1, 'clocked_in' => now()]
            );
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            echo "crap";
        }
    }
}
```

and the buttons in my view:

```
                        <div id="start">
                            @csrf
                            <button
                                class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"
                                type="button"
                                id="start-btn"
                                name="start-btn"
                                value="start"
                            >start</button>
                        </div>
```

I'm sorry if that is some common issue I should have figured out by myself but I'm new to PHP and in particular Laravel 7. Also I never used AJAX before and I couldn't find a solution to a similiar problem for days.

So my question is: Can I use AJAX to give those buttons the wanted functionality without reloading my page, so without a "form" and without giving data to my JQuery function like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#start-btn').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("flag");

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: "/home",
            success: function(result){
                alert("Welcome!");
                console.log("flag2");
            }});
    });
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214247/discussion-on-question-by-kolosz-using-ajax-to-call-a-php-function-without-data).

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to simply submit a form without `<form>` tag using ajax, try this.**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#start-btn').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        url: "{{ route('home.find') }}",
        data: { start_btn: "start-btn", _token:@json(csrf_token()) },
        success: function(result){
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function(result){
            console.log(result);
        }
       });
});
```

**Now from controller just return `$request->start_btn` and you will get `start-btn` as text in console. When you receive the value in console then you can continue your work.**